# openshift git not working

Tags: git, jboss, openshift-online-2

I have uploaded code to my openshift JBoss server before but when I upload some code today there are no changes when I open the page in the browser.
When I use git I use these commands:

```
git add . --all
git commit -m "newcomment2"
git push
```

when I use `git show` I get a strange response:

```
error: cannot run pager: No such file or directory
commit 3e1a0025bf9746fdb1e0329819f7cf79e3e8f8e4
Author: root <slenkar@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Oct 8 16:02:17 2014 -0400

newbloke2

diff --git a/upload.sh b/upload.sh
deleted file mode 100755
index 606b8af..0000000
--- a/upload.sh
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,4 +0,0 @@
-#!/bin/sh
-git add . --all
-git commit -m "newbloke2"
-git push
\ No newline at end of file
```

There should be a lot of other files on the server, it is only showing one, which is a SH script I made but wanted to delete.

Answer (score 2):

This may be the result of the pager setting in your global .gitconfig.

You can set it using `GIT_PAGER=cat` parameter.

As mentioned in [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183920/3506015) stackoverflow answer you can also set it to not use a pager:

> git --no-pager show

Alternatively, you could use the `-p` argument to paginate using `less`.

**e.g.**  `git -p show`

To view you `git` configuration settings, use:

`git config --list`

Then check for a `core.pager` setting.

*git_config man page*

```
core.pager
           The command that git will use to paginate output. Can be overridden with the GIT_PAGER environment variable. Note that git sets the LESS environment variable to FRSX if it
           is unset when it runs the pager. One can change these settings by setting the LESS variable to some other value. Alternately, these settings can be overridden on a project
           or global basis by setting the core.pager option. Setting core.pager has no affect on the LESS environment variable behaviour above, so if you want to override git’s default
           settings this way, you need to be explicit. For example, to disable the S option in a backward compatible manner, set core.pager to less -+$LESS -FRX. This will be passed to
           the shell by git, which will translate the final command to LESS=FRSX less -+FRSX -FRX.
```

Comment: using git --no-pager show gets rid of the error. There seems to be only one file in the git repository but in my local repo there are about 3. When I do git push it says the repo is up to date, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a very old question, I'd like to give a short answer, since I have had the same problem.

1. Look if there is any pager-entry `core.pager` yet:

```bash
git config --list
```

2. If so, you can delete it:

```bash
git config --unset "core.pager"
# or if there are more than one:
git config --unset-all "core.pager"
```

3. Add `less` as your new pager:

```bash
git config --add "core.pager" "less"
```

And you're done.